# List AD Groups with Access to a File or Directory in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, active-directory

I'm writing code to parse through a list of file directories and identify which AD groups have access.  That info is available in the operating system under the file properties security tab, but I can't find any code examples that retrieve that info in vb.net (or c#).  Anyone have code that will do that?

Comment: Thanks Ando. I'd come close but was missing the IdentiyReference method call. I really appreciate this!  If I could vote twice for your answer I would!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [DirectorySecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx) class.

From the documentation (Application Development Foundation):

> The following code sample (which
>   requires both the
>   System.Security.AccessControl and
>   System.Security.Principal namespaces)
>   demonstrates how to display access
>   rules (DACLs) for a folder; however,
>   the same technique could be used to
>   analyze a file, registry value, or
>   other object:

```
' You could also call Directory.GetAccessControl for the following line    
Dim ds As DirectorySecurity = New DirectorySecurity("C:\Program Files", AccessControlSections.Access)
          Dim arc As AuthorizationRuleCollection = ds.GetAccessRules(True, _
          True, GetType(NTAccount))
          For Each ar As FileSystemAccessRule In arc
             Console.WriteLine(ar.IdentityReference.ToString + ": " + _
             ar.AccessControlType.ToString + " " + ar.FileSystemRights.ToString)
          Next
```